# Draw shapes with c#

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, shapes, kruskals-algorithm

I will implement Kruskal’s algorithm and I wanted to know is there any way to draw the shapes with weights? I want user somehow draw the shape below with numbers so I could do the rest.

Is that possible? If yes how? I need some ideas.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible! Have a look at the Graphics-object.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How I could do it? Using DrawLines(Pen, Point[]) or what?

Comment: Please refine you're question. What isn't working and what do you need first?
You can draw a line in winforms form_OnPaint event with e.Graphics.DrawLine(X,Y,X2,Y2).

Comment: I didn't try anything I didn't know that is even possible.. I just need one example how user could draw something like the image above with letters A,B,C, etc and their weights 7,8,5 etc.

Comment: read the part on Line Charts over at CodeProject http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35092/Charts-for-Windows-Application-using-C

Comment: @Wimbo I think this is exactly what I need... Will check it right now

Comment: @Loclip Doing it all from scratch will be quite a bit of work. Maybe you should have allok at one of these libraries: http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/ or http://nodexl.codeplex.com/ or http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can post an image of the result you would expect?

So far I think you need to know about two different topics. First is how to draw/render own graphic objects and second is how a user can interact and draw. Refer to [Canvas Implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6238/Canvas-implementation-for-C)